# Throwing std::exception crashes Visual Studio 2013 IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I've just filed a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807509/throw-std-runtime-error-crashes-visual-studio-2013-ide) to Microsoft, on my system throwing any exception with `std::exception` or those that inherit it crashes the Visual Studio 2013 IDE. Have anyone else seen this problem or is it a quirk on my system that enables the bug? I can also mention that my Visual Studio 2012 on the same system have not such issues.

The following minimalist example crashes my Visual Studio 2013 IDE:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv [])
{
    try
    {
        throw std::exception("Crashtest");
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error" << std::endl; // never reached
    }

    return 0; // never reached
}
```

Anyone have a suggestion for a work-around until they have fixed this, it's quite annoying at the moment.

**Update**

Intel has posted a workaround for this bug here:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/494680

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some further investigation on this bug this weekend. First I uninstalled Windows 7 and upgraded to Windows 8.1 Enterprise (64-bit). Then I installed Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 (v12.0.21005 REL). I ran the program below with no problems and I thought that I had fixed the problem. However, when I installed Intel C++ Studio XE 2013 (included SP1 with update 1) the bug came back. So there seem (at least on my system) to be an issue with how Visual Studio 2013 and Intel C++ Studio 2013 works together.

Comment: I have the same error, uninstalling intel compiler in an attempt to get VS2013 usable again. It didn't always do this, so maybe its a recent intel c++ update that broke everything.

Comment: @Programmdude I've reported the bug to Intel if you want to follow the  discussion http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/487841 It may help the speed at which they fix this by adding a comment there that you also have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a new C++ Console application, with precompiled header, and then pasted your code. I was not able to recreate the issue. I'm able to place a breakpoint on `std::cerr <<` and hit it without fault.

Have you tried re-installing Visual Studio 2013? I'm guessing you have a corrupt installation or a misconfigured debugger. Make sure to remove previous versions of Visual Studio. Even though they work side-by-side I've seen issues previously with native debugging.

Comment: I uninstalled VS 2013 and VS 2012, then I re-installed VS 2013 Ultimate, but the IDE still crashes in the same manner as described in the original post. Are you running Win 7 SP1 also?

Comment: Yes VS 2013 Professional on Windows 7 x64 Professional SP1. I've tried this on three machines with the OS and VS versions now without issue.

Comment: I think I must re-install Windows since re-installing Visual Studio won't work - also, `ntdll.dll` is the shared library where the crash happends and that's a Windows file, perhaps it's something wrong with that file or one of its dependencies. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled C++ exception handling with option `/EHsc`.

Comment: I just checked now and C++ exception handling is enabled already with option `/EHsc`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck in this problem for 3 days until I discovered that the problem was in try-catch blocks. Viewing this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx, I realized the importance of not leaving a "catch" empty. Remove the try catch block and check, please.

Well, this problem happened to me while developing a simple sequential workflow SharePoint 2013 in Visual Studio 2013 in "OnTaskChanged" methods.

I hope the answer may help someone else.